# Stability and global symmetries of complex scalar field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, symmetry, stability

Given the Lagrangian of a complex scalar field:
$$ \mathcal L = \partial_{\mu} \phi^* \partial^{\mu} \phi - m^2 \phi^* \phi - \frac 12 \mu^{4-2n} \phi^{2n} - \frac 12 (\mu^*)^{4-2n} (\phi^*)^{2n} \, ,$$

where $\mu$ is a complex parameter and $n \in N$.

1. Is still possible to say that charge conjugation is a global symmetry?
2. For which values of $\mu$ and $n$ the system is stable?

---

- For the first question I'm in doubt if one can opportunely choose the phase $\eta$ that the fields acquires with a charge conjugation $U(C)$:
  $$ U(C) \phi U^{+}(C) = \eta \phi \, , $$
  such that it is a symmetry of the Lagrangian ( $\eta^{2n} = 1$ ).
- For the second I'm not sure of what "stable" means. Should I find the minima of the potential?
  $$ V(\phi , \phi^*) = m^2 \phi^* \phi + \frac 12 \mu^{4-2n} \phi^{2n} + \frac 12 (\mu^*)^{4-2n} (\phi^*)^{2n} \, .$$

Comment: Stable typically means that the potential has a minimum.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.